# Twython Stream: did you reach the volume limit or not?

Tags: twitter, twython

I am using Twython with the streaming API to retrieve specific tweets. There is a limitation of 1% of the total volume of tweets that can be gathered. If a request reaches this limit (https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/2907), there should be an entry in the json file like

```
{"limit":{"track":1234}}
```

I tried to reach the limit by tracking every tweet that contains 'the' or every tweet in the whole world with location='-180.,-90.,180,90.' but I never got this limit/track.
Could you tell me if I can have access to it with Twython?
Best regards,
F.